# Angular directive loading order.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a view containing two nested directives. The inner-directive depends upon the outer-directive to be present. When I load the page from scratch the directives are loaded as expected i.e the outer exists before the inner. But when I navigate from the page and then return, the order of directive-loading is reversed i.e the inner-directive is loaded before the outer-directive. Both directives are costume directives. When I change the outer-directive to instead being a ng-controller, the problem is solved. To perform the navigation ui-router is used. Does anybody know how to solve this issue without having to use a ng-controller as the outer-directive? And why ng-controller solves the problem?

```
<div outer-directive>
    <inner-directive></inner-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: There isnt really enough info to go on, without knowing what the controller actually does, or what is in each directive. Are you able to create a snippet or a jsfiddle to demo this?

Comment: Does inner-directive have a dependency listed?  I.e. require: '^outerDirective' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing a ton about your specific directives, you can take a look a [this blog post](http://www.newyyz.com/blog/2014/12/15/understanding-priorities-in-angularjs-directive-definition-objects/) about directive priority.

(Controller gets processed in a different cycle than directives, so it makes sense that putting whatever 'dependent' code inner-directive requires into a controller solves your problem).

**Here's the interesting part:  Angular will follow, it appears, this "path" for your nested directives:**

outer-directive: compile

inner-directive: compile

outer-directive: pre-link

inner-directive: pre-link

inner-directive: post-link

outer-directive: post-link

The linked blog post explains "why," but this processing order explains your discrepancy between initial page load (where compile is run for the directive) and your page-back case (where the directive is already compiled and we just need to link).

Again, without knowing much about your directives, maybe you need to relocate the dependent outer-directive code into pre-link (instead of link) so that it gets processed first?

You do that by breaking up your Link object into:

```
Link: {
    pre: function(){
    }, 
    post: function() {
    }
}
```

Still need help, [here's a decent post] (http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/07/07/practical-guide-to-prelink-postlink-and-controller-methods-of-angular-directives/) on the breaking up link into pre/post.